# last_insert_id in Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, last-insert-id

In Powershell, I have a simple Mysql insert command.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, col1, col2) VALUES (1, 'two', 'three');"<br>
$command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($query, $connection)
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I'm using Mysql Connector Net 6.2.4.

Is it possible to return the `last_insert_id()` or something similar?

I've looked [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html) for some info but can't really find anything.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't there a `$command.LastInsertedId` property? If not you can always issue a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` query.